# Regarding Profile and session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

what is the basic difference between session and profile. whatever we store in session that data can be access from any page in asp.net and whatever we store in profile that data also can be access from any page in asp.net from profile. i often store user specific data in session. so i just want to know in what kind of situation we store data in profile instead of session. another things i want to know whose performance is good session or profile. please discuss. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Profile**:

1- Profile object is scoped to a particular user: 
    Each user of a web application automatically has his own profile.

2- Profile object is persistant:
    When you modify the stat os the profile object, the modifications are saved between visits to the website

3- Profile object uses the provider model to store information:
    By default, the contents of a user profile are automatically saved to a Microsoft SQL Server Express database
    located in App_Data of your web application.

4- Profile object is strongly typed:
    Using strongly typed properties has several advantages. For example, you  get full Microsoft IntelliSense when 
    using the Profile object in VS.NET 2005 or Visual Web Developer

**Session**:

1- Session object is scoped to a particular user: 
    Each user of a web application automatically has his own Session state.

2- Session object is non-persistant:
    When you add an item to the Session object, the items disappear after you leave the Web site.

3- Session object uses three different ways to be stored:
    3.1: In Process  - default
    3.2: State Server (Out of Process)
    3.3: SQL Server

4- Session object is not strongly typed:

source: [Profile VS Session](http://msmvps.com/blogs/simpleman/archive/2005/06/23/54710.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Session data will last for the lifetime of the session. Profile data is held in the asp.net database so it can persist over a number of sessions dependent on the credentials of the authenticated user.

Comment: It the conclusion that Profile is for authenticated users, and Session is for anonymous users?

Comment: @Kasper, no. Session can be used for both anonymous and authenticated users. To decide where an attribute, for an authenticated user, belongs you have to answer the question: Is the attribute more a attribute about the session/visit instance or the user? Personally, I use session for attributes that do not require persistence and change more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Other than Hawxby's and Davide Piras answers, which are technically correct, I also feel that there is a conceptual difference between Profile and Session. I feel that properties of the Profile are attributes of the session's user, where as the Session should include properties of the session. For instance, in my app I use Profile properties because I frequently call Session.Clear() for security and efficiency concerns, without worry that I'm losing attributes of the user.